# SSRS add a value to a multiselect parameter after users

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssms

I would like to have a multi-select parameter for peoples names (i.e. Jack Smith, Rob Jones …) but then after the users selects the names they want, I would like to add ‘ZZZ’ to the parameter so it would appear like the user selected this. I might have to do something in the query but I have no clue.

Comment: SSRS can't silently add another value to a multi-value parameter. You'll need to use a separate (hidden/internal) parameter and handle it on your SQL.

Comment: can you just add this to your `WHERE ` clause? Something like `WHERE PersonName IN(@myReportParameter) OR PersonName = 'ZZZ'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the parameter in a query, you can add the 'ZZZ' to the IN clause.

```
WHERE PersonName IN (@myReportParameter,'ZZZ')
```

The parameter gets converted into a string and ends up being passed as:

```
WHERE PersonName IN ('Jack Smith','Rob Jones','ZZZ')
```